# Confirm dialog postback with Textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I want create a confirm box when user wants delete his account, for that he needs to insert his password (in textbox). But I don't know how to catch the postback event and execute the method in code behind...
This is my code:

My dialog box:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
    Are you sure about this?
    Password:<asp:TextBox id="remove_password" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

My button who invokes the dialog:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_remove" Text="Delete Account" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: $('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false;" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

My script:

```
$().ready(function() { 
        $("#dialog").dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false, 
            modal: true, 
            bgiframe: true, 
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            buttons: { 
                'Delete': function() { 
                    //do something

                    //what to put here???
                    //i need to pass my textbox value or in 
                    //codebehind i do findcontrol and will work?
                    //
                },
                'Cancel': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Can someone help-me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that your dialog will popup meanwhile your postback will be executed.You cannot control this on your own if you are trying to do that in your code behind.At the most you can just use

```
 return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?');
```

Other workaround is to rely on `Javascript/Ajax` for this.

**EDIT:**

Try this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_remove" Text="Delete Account" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: I can't? if i put this <%=this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this.lb_remove))%>; will made a postback but I don't know how to catch this event :S

Comment: @user1546424 Show where you have the issue?

Comment: when user clicks on delete, what i need to do?

Comment: ? i don't have that function: confirm('...');